# Subtract data in 2 different rows

Tags: r

I have data collected at time intervals from a database. The metrics are counters, as in ever-increasing. To get the value of metric for a given time, you have to subtract one row from the previous version of the same row.

Example:

```
                 TS INST_ID         EVENT WAIT_TIME_MILLI WAIT_COUNT
2014-01-29 17:20:36       1 log file sync               1     756873
2014-01-29 17:20:36       1 log file sync               2      15627
2014-01-29 17:20:36       1 log file sync               4       2925
2014-01-29 17:21:03       1 log file sync               1     761063
2014-01-29 17:21:03       1 log file sync               2      15659
2014-01-29 17:21:03       1 log file sync               4       2929
```

Desired Output:

```
                 TS INST_ID         EVENT WAIT_TIME_MILLI WAIT_COUNT
2014-01-29 17:21:03       1 log file sync               1       4190
2014-01-29 17:21:03       1 log file sync               2         32
2014-01-29 17:21:03       1 log file sync               4          4
```

TS is the time when the metric was collected. INST_ID, EVENT, and WAIT_TIME_MILLI are static identifiers. I want to calculate the delta of the WAIT_COUNT from one TS to the next.

I've simplified the data a bit, but if it's important there are many events and can be multiple INST_IDs.

Here's the test data frame:

```
structure(list(TS = structure(c(1391034063.541, 1391034063.541, 
1391034063.541, 1391034036.136, 1391034036.136, 1391034036.136
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), INST_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), EVENT = c("log file sync", "log file sync", "log file sync", 
"log file sync", "log file sync", "log file sync"), WAIT_TIME_MILLI = c(1, 
2, 4, 1, 2, 4), WAIT_COUNT = c(761063, 15659, 2929, 756873, 15627, 
2925)), .Names = c("TS", "INST_ID", "EVENT", "WAIT_TIME_MILLI", 
"WAIT_COUNT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

Comment: See `?diff` for difference and `plyr` manual for partitioned data.frame processing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is a data.frame called dat

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- arrange(dat, WAIT_TIME_MILLI, TS)
dat <- group_by(dat, WAIT_TIME_MILLI)
dat <- mutate(dat, diff = WAIT_COUNT - lag(WAIT_COUNT))
filter(dat, !is.na(diff))
```

or:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %.%
  arrange(WAIT_TIME_MILLI, TS) %.%
  group_by(WAIT_TIME_MILLI) %.%
  mutate(diff = WAIT_COUNT - lag(WAIT_COUNT)) %.%
  filter(!is.na(diff))
```

Comment: This is great; the `data.table` / `dplyr` rosetta stone builds.

Comment: Outstanding answers @Vincent ! I implementd the dplyr solution. I also updated your dplyr answer and added EVENT to the arrange and group_by. This omission was really my fault as I simplified the data too much and only showed one EVENT. There are a number of different events I'm capturing, such as "log file sync", "log file parallel write", "db file sequential read", etc.

Answer (score 3):

@mlt's suggestion implemented in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key="TS")               # `key` orders dt by TS ascending
dt[, 
  list(
    TS=tail(TS, -1L),                        # all but first
    WAIT_COUNT=diff(WAIT_COUNT)),            # differences in WAIT_COUNT
  by=list(INST_ID, EVENT, WAIT_TIME_MILLI)   # split by these fields
]
#    INST_ID         EVENT WAIT_TIME_MILLI                  TS WAIT_COUNT
# 1:       1 log file sync               1 2014-01-29 17:21:03       4190
# 2:       1 log file sync               2 2014-01-29 17:21:03         32
# 3:       1 log file sync               4 2014-01-29 17:21:03          4
```

Basically, you break up your data by INST_ID/EVENT/WAIT_TIME, and then for each group `diff` all the values and drop the first time stamp.

EDIT: somehow failed to notice the `dput` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the data.table solution as well. I probably should have made the dput more obvious.